# How to echo js value in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a script showing below

```
 for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
        checkbox.onclick = function() {
            var currentRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;
            var secondColumn = currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

            alert("My text is: " + secondColumn.textContent );
        };
    }
```

SO I have a variable **secondcolumn** I want value of this variable in php... How can I do this...
 I have tried this in php:

1. `echo $id= secondColumn.value;`
2. `echo "<script>alert('".$id."');</script>";`

but not work anymore... Please help

Comment: Can you provide more details? What you really trying to do?

Comment: What you want to do with this variable in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use `ajax` for this:

because the main reason is `php it self`.it will be executed before even your document is loaded so you can not assign a `javascript variale` to a `php` but the `reverse is always possible`.

read here about ajax:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this, but the easiest I've found is to set some hidden value on the page/element to whatever you want to use, and then bring it into javascript.

So, on your HTML, for example:

`<td data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>"`

Then, in javascript:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
        checkbox.onclick = function() {
            var currentRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;
            var secondColumn = currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

            var el = document.querySelectorAll('td'); // You need to be more specific here....
            var your_value = el.getAttribute('data-id');

            alert("My text is: " + secondColumn.textContent );
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not append the javascript value to php variable

but you can call javascript variable just like that

```
echo "<script>alert(secondColumn);</script>";
```

Comment: This returns alert(secondColumn);

Comment: Is there any method to get variable of javascript in php

Comment: @APURVPATEL sorry i have edited my answer